# Change color using querySelector

Tags: javascript, onfocus

I'm following a Javascript tutorial using a book.
The exercise is change the background color in a `<input type="search">` using `document.querySelector`. When I try to search something with no text in the search box, the background from `<input>` changes to red. I did it using `onsubmit` and some conditional. But in the next part, it must returns to white bckground using `onfocus` and I'm not getting.

The code that I tried is

```
document.querySelector('#form-busca').onsubmit = function() {
    if (document.querySelector('#q').value == '') {
        document.querySelector('#q').style.background = 'red';
        return false;
    }
}

document.querySelector('#form-busca').onfocus = function() {
    document.querySelector('#q').style.background = 'white';
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

almost got it dude.

change:

```
document.querySelector('#form-busca').onfocus
```

to:

`document.querySelector('#q').onfocus`

revised code:

correct sample:

```
document.querySelector('#form-busca').onsubmit = function() {
    if (document.querySelector('#q').value == '') {
        document.querySelector('#q').style.background = 'red';
        return false;
    }
}

document.querySelector('#q').onfocus = function() {
    document.querySelector('#q').style.background = 'white';
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks, dude :D

Comment: I'm trying to vote but there is some bug there D:  When I vote it returns to zero lol

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the input's background color to change to white when the `input` element is focused.

Try changing your `onfocus` selector to:

`document.querySelector('#q').onfocus` ...

Answer (score 0):

You want the `onfocus` handler to be on the `#q` element, not on `#form-busca`; the form's focus doesn't matter, you want to clear the background when the input element gains focus:

```
document.querySelector('#q').onfocus = function() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
// select
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
// manipulate
h1.style.color = "red";
```

This will make the color of `h1` red.